# how can switch between scenes if the condition is true JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, switch-statement, scene

I am creating a login system using JavaFX. When the user enters correct username and password the system should open a new scene called "Dashbord".
Here is my login function:

```
public void validatelogin() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/medibase";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "0852";
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL,username,password);
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String uname = username1.getText();
    String psd = password1.getText();
    pst=connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user_account WHERE username=? and password=?");
    pst.setString(1, uname);
    pst.setString(2, psd);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){
    //loginmessagelabel.setText("Congratulations");
        switchtoSC1(null);
        
    } else{
        loginmessagelabel.setText("Login failed");
    }

}
```

When a user enters correct username and password, I have called `switchtoSC1` method, but this is not working. Here is the method:

```
public void switchtoSC1(ActionEvent event)throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Dashboard.fxml"));
    stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    scene=new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: You're passing `null` for the `event` parameter, and then calling `event.getSource()`. Obviously this will just throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: It's not clear why you need the `stage` and why you want to create a new `Scene` anyway. What's wrong with, e.g. `username1.getScene().setRoot(root);` as the second line of `switchtoSC1()`?

Answer (score 2):

As @James_D already said you have to pass a non-null event to get the stage variable, and you should also change the scene in the same stage instead of creating a new stage again, 'cause this will not take care of resources and will slow down the application.

Also, looking at your login code, I would suggest you to get the database row only by username, and then compare passwords (better if they're password hashes or much better with salted-hashes) as variables. This because resultset can be tricky and you don't want to base your authentication on it.

```
public void validateLogin(Connection conn) {

    String username = username1.getText(); // you should obviously prevent username 
                                           // duplication in the signin page code
    String password = password1.getText();

    String queryStr = "select * from user_account where username=?";

    try (PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryStr)) {

        prepStmt.setString(1, username);
        ResultSet rset = prepStmt.executeQuery();

        if (!rset.next())
            throw new LoginFailedException(); // the username doesn't match any database 
                                              // row

        byte[] passwordHash = rset.getBytes("passwordColumn"); // get the password hash from 
                                                               // the resultset

        byte[] inputHash = someHashingFunction(password); // get the input hash with the same 
                                                          // function used to store passwords, 
                                                          // so that you get the same result 
                                                          // inputting the same password

        checkHashes(passwordHash, inputHash))
        switchScene(); // some method or block to switch scenes

    } catch (LoginFailedException e) {
        // show some error scene here
    }
}

public void checkHashes(byte[] passwordHash, byte[] inputHash) throw LoginFailedException {

    for (int x = 0; x < inputHash.length; x++) {
        if (passwordHash[x] != inputHash[x]) {
            throw new LoginFailedException();
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to switch between Scenes.
When the user enters correct User Credential then the Scene change to SalaryCalcForm.fxml

**HelloApplication.java**

```
package org.xxxxx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 520, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package org.jayathilakariceproducts.jayathilakarice;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Window;
import org.jayathilakariceproducts.jayathilakarice.login.LoginDAO;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloController {

    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private Parent root;



    @FXML
    private Button loginButton;

    @FXML
    private Label loginMessageLabel;

    @FXML
    private TextArea userNameTextArea;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField passwordPasswordField;

    public void switchToSalaryCalcForm(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("salaryCalcForm.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    // use for future redirections
    public void switchToXXXXXXXXX(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("yourfxmlFile.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

//When the login button is clicked, this method executes.
// LoginDAO does the database operations.
    public void loginButtonOnAction(ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
        LoginDAO loginDAO = new LoginDAO();
         //validate inputs
        if (userNameTextArea.getText() == null || userNameTextArea.getText().isBlank()){
            loginMessageLabel.setText("User Name is Empty. Please enter the user name");
        }
        else if (passwordPasswordField.getText() == null || passwordPasswordField.getText().isBlank()){
            loginMessageLabel.setText("Password is Empty. Please enter the password");
        }
        else {
            boolean isValidate = loginDAO.isUserAuthorized(userNameTextArea.getText() , passwordPasswordField.getText());
            if (isValidate) {
                loginMessageLabel.setText("user authorized to login");
                 // swith the scene. pass argument 'e'
                switchToSalaryCalcForm(e);
            } else {
                loginMessageLabel.setText("failed to login");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it conditional if the login is correct or not. After this, create a function to load the other screen. Here is an example:

```java
if (true) {
    loadScreen();
} else {
    //dosomething
}

private void loadScreen() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/folder/file.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(new Callback<Class<?>, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call(Class<?> controllerClass) {
                if (controllerClass == ScreenFxmlController.class) {
                    ScreenFxmlController controller = new ScreenFxmlController();
                    return controller;
                } else {
                    try {
                        return controllerClass.newInstance();
                    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("/image/icon.png"));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        this.btnLogin.getScene().getWindow().hide(); //or close this Window
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("e = " + e);
    }
}
```

With this code you can pass to the other fxml objects like parameters making a setter inside of your ScreenFxmlController. It's awesome!